# WP HTTP Error: couldn't connect to host

Tags: wordpress, rss, curl

I'm running Wordpress on MAMP and for some reason I get an error on all of my RSS feeds saying

`WP HTTP Error: couldn't connect to host`

I think its a configuration problem in MAMP with cURL, but not sure how to fix it.  I have cURL enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, the proxy settings aren't set. 
Try to add this lines in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'proxy.example.com');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '8080');
```

Comment: I know this is an old question but I had the same problem and your answer was exactly what fixed the issue for me. +1, thank you.